# Get data from Postgres to Flask and convert to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, postgresql, pandas, flask

I have a Flask app that works from a csv. I put the csv as a new table in postgres, but am having trouble changing out the data connection without breaking the app.

Currently the csv is read in under a class object.  In this object, I filter the data, create a lookup table and run a machine learning algorithm (not shown for simplicity). I commented out the code where I tried to get the data from the purchases table in my_db in postgres. In the the postgres data to ultimately be a pandas dataframe.

```
class Recommender(object):

    def __init__(self):

        # df = pd.read_sql_query('select * from "purchases"',con=engine)
        # self.df = df
        df = pd.read_csv('data/20171027.csv', encoding='ISO-8859-1')
        df.date_commande_client = pd.to_datetime(df['date_commande_client'],
                                                 format='%m/%d/%y')


        df = filter_by_order_count(df) #more stuff after this


        return df
```

I tried to read in the same data from postgres but it doesn't work. Should i not be reading it in inside the class object?

For reference I tried adding these imports and creating an engine:

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine('postgresql://user:passowrd@localhost/my_db')

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = '1234'
```

Comment: *but it doesn't work*... is not helpful. Please show us the error or undesired result.

Answer (score 0):

just in case this helps: my problem was the column names in the postgres db i created were folded to lowercase and my code had some in uppercase. Once I changed certain column names it worked. Please see: [Are PostgreSQL column names case-sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20878932/are-postgresql-column-names-case-sensitive)